# getLoginURL not including client_id parameter

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to implement a FB login system on my site. I'm starting with the most simple test login page I can and hoping to build from there.

When I use the `$facebook->getLoginUrl()` method, the URL generated produces an error every time I click on it.

I noticed that the URL produced by getLoginUrl() does not include the client_id parameter in the URL string. There doesn't seem to be anything in the docs about having to set that client_id in the getLoginUrl call. I assume it's pulled from a property of the Facebook object.

Here's my code and what it outputs.

```
require_once("php-sdk/facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = /* my app id string */;
$config[‘secret’] = /* my app secret string */;
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"email"));

echo  "<a href=\"$login_url\">Login with Facebook</a>";
```

Obviously the appID and secret are the actual values. I've quadruple checked to make sure they are accurate.

The (edited) login_url generated is: 
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=[mysite]&state=[state_str]&scope=email`

It should be: 
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[appID]&redirect_uri=[mysite]&state=[state_str]&scope=email`

When I edit the URL in the browser to include client_id it works. Obviously I could manually create the correct login url myself each time, but I want to see if there's something wrong with the way I'm using Facebook::getLoginUrl()

Comment: Just realized when I saw the code pasted in here that when I copied off the Facebook documentation, it copied what should be single-quotes as smart-quotes. Thus the facebook object was not being properly initialized with the app ID and api secret. Changing them to single quotes resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized when I saw the code pasted in here that when I copied off the Facebook documentation, it copied what should be single-quotes as smart-quotes. Thus the facebook object was not being properly initialized with the app ID and api secret. Changing them to single quotes resolved the issue.